# How to define strongly typed map, based on another type

Tags: typescript

I stuck and probably need some help or just a fresh look from outside.

I have this code. The main idea is to have a type that describes **property** and connected **value type** (see type Person). And then transform it to kinda map with metadata (see const map).

```js
type Person = {
    firstName: string;
    age: number;
}

type Definition<T> = {
    value: T,
    defaultValue: T
}

type PersonDefintionMap<T> = {
    [key in keyof Person]: Definition<T>
}

const map: PersonDefintionMap<Person[keyof Person]> =
{
    age: { value: 5, defaultValue: 0 },
    firstName: { value: 'test', defaultValue: 'unknown' }
};
```

It works pretty fine, it forces me to fill all properties, and disallow me to put something not described in type Person. But it still has two weakness:

- I still can put the wrong type:

```js
const map: PersonDefintionMap<Person[keyof Person]> =
{
    age: { value: 'I AM NOT A NUMBER', defaultValue: 0 },
    firstName: { value: 'test', defaultValue: 'unknown' }
};
```

- Default value is not enforced to have the same type as value:

```js
const map: PersonDefintionMap<Person[keyof Person]> =
{
    age: { value: 1000, defaultValue: 'MY TURN TO IGNORE THE TYPE' },
    firstName: { value: 'test', defaultValue: 'unknown' }
};
```

I understand why it is happening (we use a union for type definition, but I didn't find a way to solve it. Any ideas on how to solve this? Is it possible?

Comment: `type PersonDefintionMap<T> = {
    [key in keyof Person]: Definition<Person[key]>
}`
Seems to work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass to `Definition` the type of the value (not the type of the key)

```
type DefintionMap<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: Definition<T[key]>
}

// OK
const map: DefintionMap<Person> =
{
    age: { value: 5, defaultValue: 0 },
    firstName: { value: 'test', defaultValue: 'unknown' }
};

// Error as expected
const map2: DefintionMap<Person> =
{
    age: { value: 'I AM NOT A NUMBER', defaultValue: 0 },
    firstName: { value: 'test', defaultValue: 'unknown' }
};

// Error as expected
const map3: DefintionMap<Person> =
{
    age: { value: 1000, defaultValue: 'MY TURN TO IGNORE THE TYPE' },
    firstName: { value: 'test', defaultValue: 'unknown' }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKgDMBLJYAOQEMBbCALikWHhNQHMBufQq9hqKgCuNAEYJuAX1y5QkKABEIpVCWAk0AHgAqAPkw4eBAG5UANkIHaANEagATZVSFngANXOXG23NNnhoJRV1NABZKjAdfSw8QigAbQBrCBAoNihkkGQiKG0AXUYgtjUNVB0klLzdXxkAelqoAHkAaVwAYzRmKBoIwuU2ENRwyLgkNGjcWN5+RmwoUwsBAFZrBycXd08BAAYoSVs40nJqOln5rcYAcmAIZkvVxyJnVw9Fq6FURNRkAHdUS72vm4uHqUAAovB4Mh4FAqIgoBAAB6QNo3eztTrAboRABMfWCpWGmlGKFQEymBD4AjmCy8UEuAEkoABBUJQCiNbQs9kAVVCACEwQAle5rJ4bV503b7OxHZgnannN70m53B7rF4XekfL6-f6AyTA0EQqEwuEI5EQVEQdEdVBdHpgADM+IGhIixIQpPJdipZ1pAgAjNsQ+rxZrlZdQgBNXI8oUUXKNKAMgDiHKFYNyAAks9pozAwQCZYcyPLaIqA1dVcBRY9nptIzrvn9i0CgA)

Comment: So a nice and simple solution, thank you very much!